# Spring framework configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mongo

It has been 3 days since I started learning about Spring Framework and trying to implement a RESTful web service with MongoDB and Spring Framework. I am still at the beginning and trying to understand the configuration of Spring Framework. When I start my project and hit the desired URL it is not working. I have also upload my project to github [(here is the url)](https://github.com/gabbyturk/sowws)

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         id="WebApp_ID"
         version="2.4"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="shoponway.webservice" />
    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Loads MongoDB configuraton -->
    <import resource="mongo-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

**and my controller**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    @Resource(name = "personService")
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allpersons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllPersons(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("persons", personService.getAllPersons());
        return "personspage";
    }
}
```

**The error I am getting**

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: are you getting any error. is your context getting up properly ?

Comment: yes I insert the error by editing the question

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear: you did not define the "personService" bean in your context.

Comment: where can I define it and how? in applicationContext.xml or spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: You are using a very old version of Spring, and I recommend looking at the JavaConfig option and Spring Boot. They make configuration a lot simpler and are an easier starting point.

Comment: OK. I have just updated spring from 3.2.0 to 4.0.2.RELEASE. nothing changed really. I am still getting the error in my question

Comment: @Emilla did your problem solved?

Comment: At least I am not getting any error now when I use mongo-config.xml shared by @Santosh Joshi below. However When I hit the URL i got 404 not found exception. I really have no idea about routing strategy of spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this example, which can be corrected as follows

1. add `@Service` anotation to your `shoponway.webservice.services.PersonService` class, you need to add `@Service` for making it a proper candidate for injection.
2. Your 'mongo-config.xml' is pointing to wrong mongo repository locations edit it to 
      `<mongo:repositories base-package="shoponway.webservice.services" />`
   from
   `<mongo:repositories base-package="org.krams.tutorial.repositories" />`
3. Mongo template should refer to following bean `<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">` not  with `class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate"`

4) replace mongo-config.xml content with

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="shoponwaydb" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

 </beans>
```

`

Once your correct these , you will be able to run your example easily:

Comment: I did everything you told. And I am still getting an error but at least this error trace is small. I insert new error trace.

Comment: check for spring-web.3.2.0.RELEASE jar in your target/WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Its running fine for me, with these changes only i am able to run this example. Please check the jars you was in your WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: as I updated spring dependencies in pom, I have spring-web.4.0.2.RELEASE jar in  target/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Really so weird. After I applied the changes you told, maven throws "Unable to configure" error. Altough I can see maven dependencies in project structure, I can not see them in Deployment Assembly

Comment: i forked out your repo and checked in the changes to new repo. please check out `https://github.com/santoshjoshi/sowws/tree/master/SOW-WS`  and try running the example

Comment: I got the new project from your git repository. And When I start server it throwed this exception : SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ReadPreference

Comment: does it mean my mongo instance is not available?

Comment: upgrade your mongo-driver version, seems some classes are missing in mongo-java-driver.2.4.jar, update it with  `<version>2.11.3</version>`

Comment: it is worked. But the error changed now.I am getting this error now :(
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo-config.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: `MongoTemplate` only accepts the first two params from your mongo-config.xml file, remove the  `<constructor-arg name="defaultCollectionName" value="person"/>` argument to make it working

Comment: my friend, it is not working again. A different error again : 
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: hmm, replace your mongo-config.xml content with one i pasted above, reduild your code after cleaning up

Comment: when I use your mongo-config content above, xml throws an error. I really can not believe spring configuration is so difficult.
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/santoshjoshi/sowws/tree/master/SOW-WS: https://github.com/santoshjoshi/sowws/tree/master/SOW-WS/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
(continue ...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48800/discussion-between-santosh-joshi-and-emilla)

Comment: @Emilla, seems the error is from eclipse, and your are looking at wrong location: https://github.com/santoshjoshi/sowws

Comment: Thanks @Santosh Joshi when change your mongo-config by inserting this it worked.
<!-- Offers convenience methods and automatic mapping between MongoDB JSON documents and your domain classes. -->
   <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
      <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="shoponwaydb"/>
   </bean>

Comment: @SantoshJoshi really liked your solution especially the part where you pointed the mongo bean to be used not with class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate"

Comment: @Pan Thanks for appreciating :).